# Tailwind Custom Colors Not Complied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, craco

On `npm start (craco start)` everything **works fine** and colors are being compiled.

When running `npm run build (craco build)` though, **only one color of each configuration is being compiled**, `dallas` from `theme.textColor` and `vista-white` from `theme.gradientColorStops`.

I tried:

- Reordering `theme.textColor` properties.
- Deleting `node_modules` and `npm i`.
- Deleting the `build` and rebuilding.

```js
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
    },
  },
};
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    textColor: (theme) => ({
      ...theme('colors'),
      dallas: '#664A2D',
      'blue-charcoal': '#24292E',
      denim: '#0D66C2',
      'spring-green': '#05E776',
      flamingo: '#E65A4D',
    }),
    gradientColorStops: (theme) => ({
      ...theme('colors'),
      'vista-white': '#E1DFDC',
    }),
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: It sounds as though your styles are being purged. Are you actually *using* them in your mark-up?

Comment: Yes I am, @George. And IntelliSense is also showing them in VSCode. You may check the website here (`hover:denim` on my linkedin icon for example): https://aboqasem.dev/
Source code: https://github.com/aboqasem/aboqasem.dev/blob/main/src/pages/Home.tsx#L29

Comment: Purge will not recognise your usage of this class. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html. Specifically, *"Don't use string concatenation to create class names"*. Purge is not 'smart' in any way, it works by matching your utilities against classes (or any string, really..) throughout your templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot @George! Do you recommend using `safelist: ['bg-red-500', 'px-4'],` option? Or refactor my `IContact.color` to have `text-denim` instead of `denim` (I don't think this will work right?)?

Comment: Oh I think it does: https://regex101.com/r/9XRVMP/1

Comment: It does indeed. Which route you take is up to your requirements. A safelist can prevent the purging of utilities that may not be known to you at build time. Since you *do* know the names of utilities used, I'd probably prefer the former option (explicitly naming classes in your object).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [@George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612146/george) for pointing out the problem:

> Purge will not recognise your usage of this class. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html. Specifically, "Don't use string concatenation to create class names". Purge is not 'smart' in any way, it works by matching your utilities against classes (or any string, really..) throughout your templates.

One possible solution is to add the classes that are being purged to `purge.options.safelist`:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // Added safelist
  purge: {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
    options: {
      safelist: ['hover:text-blue-charcoal', 'hover:text-denim', 'hover:text-spring-green', 'hover:text-flamingo'],
    },
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    textColor: (theme) => ({
      ...theme('colors'),
      dallas: '#664A2D',
      'blue-charcoal': '#24292E',
      denim: '#0D66C2',
      'spring-green': '#05E776',
      flamingo: '#E65A4D',
    }),
    gradientColorStops: (theme) => ({
      ...theme('colors'),
      'vista-white': '#E1DFDC',
    }),
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If u use Tailwind 3 you can :

```
module.exports = {
 theme: {
extend: {
  colors: {
    'regal-blue': '#243c5a',
    },
   }
  }
 }
```

Just add "extend" if no use, All colors will be reset
This allows you not to have to use the safelist

Answer (score -1):

To customize text colors in the Tailwind you need to configure tailwind.config.js like this

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    textColor: {
      'primary': '#3490dc',
      'secondary': '#ffed4a',
      'danger': '#e3342f',
    }
  }
}
```

You can refer to Tailwind [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color#customizing) for more information.